# Android Getting Intent from Service Class to extended Service Class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, notifications

Any Android gurus around? Please help solve this...

I have an activity class that passes Intent data to Service Class as follows

Activity Class

```
public class UsherActivity extends ListActivity {
    ...

    public void createNotification() {

        int subtotal = 580;


        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, SampleOverlayService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("box", "8");
        serviceIntent.putExtra("tot", subtotal);
        startService(serviceIntent);

    }
}
```

My SampleOverlayService Class is as follows: Note the "subtotal_from_intent_putExtra_Here"...this is where i would like the data to show.

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;

import android.content.Intent;

public class SampleOverlayService extends OverlayService {

    public static SampleOverlayService instance;

    private SampleOverlayView overlayView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        instance = this;

        overlayView = new SampleOverlayView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (overlayView != null) {
            overlayView.destory();
        }

    }

    static public void stop() {
        if (instance != null) {
            instance.stopSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Notification foregroundNotification(int notificationId) {
        Notification notification;

        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "getString(R.string.title_notification), System.currentTimeMillis());

        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "subtotal_from_intent_putExtra_Here", getString(R.string.message_notification), notificationIntent());

        return notification;
    }


    private PendingIntent notificationIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleOverlayHideActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return pending;
    }

}
```

And the OverlayService Class is as follows

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class OverlayService extends Service {

    protected boolean foreground = false;
    protected boolean cancelNotification = false;
    protected int id = 0;

    protected Notification foregroundNotification(int notificationId) {
        return null;
    }

    public void moveToForeground(int id, boolean cancelNotification) {
        moveToForeground(id, foregroundNotification(id), cancelNotification);
    }

    public void moveToForeground(int id, Notification notification, boolean cancelNotification) {
        if (! this.foreground && notification != null) {
            this.foreground = true;
            this.id = id;
            this.cancelNotification = cancelNotification;

            super.startForeground(id, notification);
        } else if (this.id != id && id > 0 && notification != null) {
            this.id = id;
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(id, notification);
        }
    }


    public void moveToBackground(int id, boolean cancelNotification) {
        foreground = false;
        id = 0;
        super.stopForeground(cancelNotification);
    }

    public void moveToBackground(int id) {
        moveToBackground(id, cancelNotification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I've honestly tried different approaches to no avail. I just get java.lang.nullPointerException since the intent.getExtras()... returns null wherever I place it. How do I get subtotal into the notification?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I'm basing from https://gist.github.com/bjoernQ/6975256

Comment: Where is exactly you calling intent.getExtras()?

Comment: override the function onStartCommand and thats where you can get the intent

Comment: @has 19 Yes, I get that it is being delivered to onStartCommand of the OverlayService Class... but how do i call it in SampleOverlayService Class and assign it to String?

Comment: @Mahfuz...I left that open so you can help place that... wherever I placed intent.getExtras() in SampleOverlayService, I got null. thanks

Comment: override `onStartCommand` in `SampleOverlayService`, and `intent.getStringExtra()`

Comment: @li2 would u kindly put that in code...the idea is to pass the string into the foregroundnotification method

Comment: I am wonder who will call `moveToBackground` and `moveToBackground`?

Comment: Yes...i had tried to change foregroundNotification(int notificationId) to foregroundNotification(int notificationId, String data) but couldn't get string data from intent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onStartCommand(Intent intent,, int flags, int startId)` in `SampleOverlayService`.

Code :

```
public class SampleOverlayService extends OverlayService {

private int totalCount = 0;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        totalCount = intent.getIntExtra("tot", 0);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

This will get value in `totalCount` variable and you can use this value accordingly.

Comment: I figured it out about a day before you but you are right... i did it the same way as you, thank you for elaborating... and for that you get the tick... cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Intent is delivered to 'onStartCommand' method

Comment: Yes, I get that it is being delivered to onStartCommand of the OverlayService Class... but how do i call it in SampleOverlayService Class and assign it to String?